# (ruby on rails) How to use "remote" in search_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, html-select

There is a select tag, I want to realize the function that once an option is chosen, corresponding results will be shown below.

Here is my code:

```
<%= select_tag :institute, options_for_select(Course::INSTITUTE_LIST), data: {remote: true,  url: url_for(controller: 'courses_store', action: 'index')} %>
```

and my controller:

```
class CoursesStoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    institute = params[:institute]
     @courses = Course.paginate :page => params[:page],
                                  :per_page => 10,
                                  :conditions => ["institute like ?", "%#{institute}%"],
                                  :order => 'institute',
                                  :order => 'name'
    @page_now = params[:page]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @courses }
    end
  end
end
```

But there is no reponse when I click the options. Can you help me with this? Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) has this `:data` tag.

I should suggest you to use `ajax`.

**Update**

give a `class` or `id` to your `select_tag`

```
<%= select_tag :institute, options_for_select(Course::INSTITUTE_LIST), :id => "institute"%>
```

then write some script

```
<script>
$("#institute").change(function() {
  var institute = $("#institute").val
   $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<%= path_of_your_controller_action %>",
        data: {institute: institute},
        dataType:'script',
            beforeSend: function(){
                // do whatever you want
            },
            success: function(response){
                // do whatever you want
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: but i don't know how to realize it with ajax. Can you give me a sample?

Comment: you can get this institute with `params[:institute]`

Comment: but my current page still had no response